# Moq - Can't mock a class property's method return value

Tags: c#, moq

How can I mock the `CasOperations.GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync()` method so that it returns the mocked value?  Currently, I am getting an exception (shown below the code examples).

I have the following setup:

**Class and property to be mocked:**

```
public class BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry : NWatchCustomScheduleEntryBase, INWatchCustomScheduleEntry
{
    public BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry(INWatchSchedulerApplication application)
        : base(application, DevOpsScheduleFrequency.Minute, 15, 0, DevOpsScheduleFlags.Always)
    {
        // Some initialization for below properties
        CasOperations = new CasOperations(cas, EntityService, IsBranchesOnly);
    }

    public CasOperations CasOperations { get; private set; }

}

public class CasOperations
{
    public CasOperations(CasApi casApi, BranchCircuitEntityService entityService, bool isBranchesOnly)
    {
        CAS = casApi;
        this.entityService = entityService;
        this.isBranchesOnly = isBranchesOnly;
    }
}
```

**Test that tries to perform mocking:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void DownNodeRediscoveredInSpectrum()
{
    var mock = new Mock<BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry>(_application);
    mock.CallBase = true;

    // Spectrum's artificial response with a model with the same name, but a "new" model handle
    var mockedNewlyImpairedNodes = new NetworkDeviceNodeStatus[]
    {
        new NetworkDeviceNodeStatus
        {
            // Not important
        }
    };

    mock.Setup(x =>
        x.CasOperations.GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync()).ReturnsAsync(mockedNewlyImpairedNodes);
}
```

**Exception thrown in the test:**

> An exception of type
>   'Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException'
>   occurred in Moq.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Can not instantiate proxy of class:
>   NWatch.NetworkCircuits.CasOperations. Could not find a parameterless
>   constructor.

Comment: Well you certainly need an instance of `CasOperations` to call a method on it.  Maybe you should make an `ICasOperations` instead, which will be easy to inject a mock object into.

Comment: But, the mocked BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry already has an instance.  I was hoping that I can just have Moq override one of its methods, and return the value I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow me to give it a try:

In the setup of the mock you are not trying to mock the behaviour of the `BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry`, but the behaviour of the `CasOperations` class. So you really need a `Mock<CasOperations>` object. Or even better, a `Mock<ICasOperations>` as @Jonesopolis said in his comment.

Besides, in the `BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry` constructor you are initializing both the instance of that class and the instance of `CasOperations`. It would be better if you initialize the instance of `CasOperations` outside the `BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry` constructor and pass it as a parameter.

So it would be like this:

```
public class BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry : NWatchCustomScheduleEntryBase, INWatchCustomScheduleEntry
{
    public BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry(INWatchSchedulerApplication application, ICasOperations casOperations)
        : base(application, DevOpsScheduleFrequency.Minute, 15, 0, DevOpsScheduleFlags.Always)
    {
        CasOperations = casoperations;
    }

    public CasOperations CasOperations { get; private set; }
}
```

Finally, you create your mock, set it up and pass it as a parameter to the `BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry` constructor:

```
var casMock = new Mock<ICasOperations>();
casMock.Setup(x => x.GetImpairedNodesFromCASpectrumAsync()).ReturnsAsync(mockedNewlyImpairedNodes);

var mock = new Mock<BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry>(_application, casMock.Object);
mock.CallBase = true;
```

Note that maybe this last instance of `BranchCircuitStatusScheduleEntry` should not be a mock, but a real object (the instance under test).

Comment: Thank you Carlos!  You are absolutely right that the CasOperations needs to be the mocked item.  As for accepting it as a parameter, unfortunately, I cannot do this because this class is instantiated and invoked by a scheduler, which only expects that parameters given.